# How to deal with Necro (zombie) virus in Plaugue inc

Tags: pc, plague-inc-evolved

I am having hard time dealing with Necro virus on normal...

Specifically cure gets created faster when it normally does and even with 100% spread while remaining unnoticed I am just not lethal enough..., **what strategy could I use to eradicate humanity?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so one way to do this is to save up 77 plague upgrade points and have all the humanity infected (to make it easier get the anti-mutation perk)
You can just use normal hidden ways to get to this point, then upgrade symptom tree in following way: Salvation - Galapagia - Gastro - Cannibalism - Cytoplasmic Reanimation - Anaerobic Resuscitator, and you should be good.

[I have also created a video](https://www.youtube.com/edit?video_id=ouMJuwNYQFo)...